# Air speed velocity of a windy situation

Tags: stability

This is perhaps a really obvious question but I just want to make sure...

If the wind is blowing at 40 km/h, do I need a drone with a max speed of 40 km/h in order to stay stable?

In other words, is maintaining a ground speed of 0 in 40km/h wind, the same as maintaining 40 km/h ground speed when air speed is 0?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it's a bit like standing on the bank of a river and watching a boat fight the current. In order for the boat to look like it's standing still, it needs to be moving through the water at the same speed as the river is flowing.

In reality you really want a top speed well in excess of the wind speed. Partly because the wind is faster at altitude than at ground level, so it might not feel too bad when you launch, but could be much stronger when you're flying. Also because you generally don't just hover in place. If you fly down-wind, you'll have to fight your way back against the wind.